# MinGW doesn't have the libtclstub.a and libtkstub.a libraries so TCL won't compile

Tags: c, tcl, mingw, tk-toolkit, mingw-w64

Using: Windows 10 64-bit with MINGW64 on Git Bash.

I've been trying to compile a TCL package in MinGW (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) (which the package said to use), but `C:\MinGW\lib` doesn't contain either `libtclstub.a` or `libtkstub.a`, so it is impossible to compile the package. I'm new to MinGW and have no idea how to add them.

When I run `../configure` in Git Bash, it just prints:

```
css.o:css.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
css.o:css.c:(.text+0xcf): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x965): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x9bb): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x9cc): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xab2): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xc2b): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xc89): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xc9b): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xe22): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xef6): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xf08): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xf44): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xf8b): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0xff7): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1030): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1088): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1093): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x12fd): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1388): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1408): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x15e3): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x19cf): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1a3b): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1a50): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x1b58): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x2033): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x275b): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x2787): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x27ed): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x27f8): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x287c): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x28bd): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x28cc): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x2a00): more undefined references to `tkStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x310b): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x3b85): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x49ef): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4a37): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4a93): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4c0a): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4cd9): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4e0f): undefined reference to `tclStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x4e38): more undefined references to `tclStubsPtr' follow
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x55c4): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x55d5): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x566a): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x5754): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x57b8): undefined reference to `tkIntXlibStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x5847): undefined reference to `tkStubsPtr'
htmldraw.o:htmldraw.c:(.text+0x58d7): more undefined references to `tkStubsPtr' follow
[etc...]
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:273: libTkhtml3.0] Error 1
```

I tried downloading `libtclstub.a` and `libtkstub.a` from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/blob/main/mingw32/lib/libtclstub86.a (same for TK), and add them to `C:\MinGW\lib`, but then got:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libtclstub86.a(tclStubLib.o):(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libtclstub86.a(tclStubLib.o):(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libtclstub86.a(tclStubLib.o):(.text+0x1b2): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libtkstub86.a(tkStubLib.o):(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libtkstub86.a(tkStubLib.o):(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libtkstub86.a(tkStubLib.o):(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:273: libTkhtml3.0] Error 1
```

I suppose I haven't installed something I should have but I'm not exactly sure what that is, nor how to install it. There also may be other files I need that I'm unaware of, though those could be installed with the stub libraries.

Comment: libtclstub.a and libtkstub.a both should come from TCL/Tk (Tool Command Language/ToolKit) you can either install tcl and tk via the package manage that came with mingw64 and/or msys2 (both of which I'm assuming that you've installed).  Failing that you can always download the tcl/tk source package (see https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) and build from source code -- although I'm betting that there this will show up more missing libraries/dependancies.

Comment: @thurizas
I have been able to use `C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\guimain` the "MinGW Installation Manager" to install `mingw32-tcl` and `mingw32-tk`, but then the file the compiler outputted was a "`.0` flie" when it should be a `.dll`  file, and is only (roughly) half the size it should be.

Comment: when compiling shared library with gcc (or mingw) the command line is a bit more complicated then just `gcc test.c -o test`.  For example, after compiling your files to object files `gcc -c test.c -o test.o`, you would use a command like `gcc -o test.dll test.o -s -shared -Wl,--subsystem,windows`  See ttps://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/ for more information and a full example.  I do not use VS Code so I have no idea on how to configure its compile task to actuall produce a dynamic library.